# Call Stream.stream.listen() twice with StreamBuilder?

Tags: flutter

I am using `StreamBuilder` and putting an instance of `StreamController.stream` into it.

```dart
late StreamController c;
late Stream s;

initState() {
  c = StreamController();
  s = c.stream;
  super.initState();
}

Widget build(context) {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: s,
    builder: (context, snap) {
      return Container(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed:() => setState(() {
            //calling setState will re-build StreamBuilder
          }),
        ),
      };
    }
  );
}
```

Since the `StreamBuilder` will be rebuilt on every `setState` call, how do I prevent `StreamBuilder` from trying to re-listen to `Stream` **without** making it a `Broadcast` stream (since `Stream`s can only be listened to once)?

Answer (score 2):

A `StreamBuilder` doesn't do anything with its stream when it's rebuilt if the stream is the same. There is no re-listening so it's not necessary to do anything special here.

Evidence can be found in the implementation of `StreamBuilder` and `StreamBuilderBase` in the [Flutter source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/async.dart). Action is only taken if the new stream differs from the old one.

```dart
@override
void didUpdateWidget(StreamBuilderBase<T, S> oldWidget) {
  super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  if (oldWidget.stream != widget.stream) {
    if (_subscription != null) {
      _unsubscribe();
      _summary = widget.afterDisconnected(_summary);
    }
    _subscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: What if the StreamBuilder is changed? Like if it was replaced by another widget in the tree and then a StreamBuilder is put back in the same position?

Comment: @KernelJames If that's the case then `StreamBuilder` is not a good option for what you're doing. You would need to maintain the subscription to the stream at a point in the widget tree where it won't be disposed. This might be accomplished by removing your `StreamBuilder` and listening to the stream in the initState of the widget you show in your question.